# How can I hunt legendary animals when there is too much activity in the area?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

When entering an area of a legendary animal, sometimes I get a message like the following:

> You have entered legendary animal territory, but there is too much activity to track the animal

Is this simply a time issue, do I have to return at a different time? Or does it have anything to do with me being too noisy? What do I need to do to hunt the legendary animal when I get that message?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this as well. Not sure of the cause. I tried giving it time, setting up camp and sleeping overnight... but what ended up working for me was to save the game and reload. When I reloaded, it put me just outside of the legendary animal area. As I approached the legendary animal area, it alerted me that I should look for clues, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Leave the area and return later. If an area is not used for a while, it gets overwritten in memory by the game, and will "re-roll". The lowest time that's worked for me was 2 minutes.